# I want to know the difference between ざじずぜぞ And だぢづでど

Tags: pronunciation

They all sound so similar to me, I want to know how I can tell the difference these since they make the same sound. (Please excuse me if I’m wrong I’m very new to Japanese and currently learning hiragana)

Comment: If you speak English with any amount of ease, then distinguishing between ざ (za) and だ (da) should not be difficult. じ and ぢ are essentially pronounced identically in modern standard Japanese.  Similarly ず and づ are pronounced the same.  Historically there may have been differences between these, but I don't know anything about that.  As for ぜ (ze) ,で (de),  ぞ (zo), and ど (do), these are pronounced as indicated in the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, if you are not a native English speaker, that is helpful to know, because it will allow the answerer to understand the position you are asking the question from.

Comment: my native language is english but this helped a lot as well since I struggle with it sometimes since I like to talk a lot in spanish. Thank you for adding the pronunciations! It is very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Mikiko Iwasaki. すみません。My name probably appears in Kanji. I am a native Japanese speaker and a professional Japanese language teacher. Historically, 「じ」and 「ぢ」have different sounds, and「ず」and 「づ」have different sounds. But in modern Japanese, they are pronounced the same in most areas in Japan, じ[ji], ぢ[ji], and ず[zu], づ[zu]. As Ellettさん writes, ざ[za] and だ[da] have different sounds. ざline syllables have [z] + [a], [e], [o], and だline syllables have [d] + [a], [e], [o].  If you can pronounce or if you can check the pronunciation of "Zambia," the name of the country, and "diamond," the first sounds of each word are similar to ざ[za] and だ[da]. So, please try.

Comment: thank you so much! I was actually watching a video and it sounded like both were saying it with D. Im glad that it's cleared up now.

Comment: Remember to click the check mark if this answered your question, so other people can see it when they find this question.